# How can I find the FULL PATH for a file that is located in the "Program Files" (Windows 8)

Tags: windows, path

I'm having trouble finding the full path for an executable file in Windows 8. I tried the "hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, right click, and copy as path" method. But that doesn't seem to work with EXE files in the program files directory.

It really shouldn't be this hard. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand the problem?  There is kiting special about the folder in explorer itself (it's only write protected to a certain extent )

Comment: I have no issue with the "hold shift, right click, and copy as path" method. Do you get an error? Is the path not copied?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest opening up a command prompt window and do:

```
cd \

dir /s /n ***executableprogramname***
```

Answer (score 0):

My way of getting the full path to files (if I'm using [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) to navigate) is just to tell Windows to show the full path.

First, if you have Windows 7 (or later) then all you need to do is just left-click with your mouse on the navigation bar (where you see the folders "tree" like C -> Program Files -> dir, and it will automatically change to the folder path.

Then just start writing your file name (you can even use the auto-complete) and then copy paste the path.

Comment: But doesn't using Windows 8 imply using the tiles interface?